# $ionicPlatform.ready don't fire if acces view by $location.path

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a controller called `RateProfilesCtrl`, I'm using a promise that resolves when `$ionicPlatform.ready` is ready.

The issue is, if I go to `RateProfilesCrl` clicking in a link like `<a href="#/tab/rate-profiles">GO!</a>` works perfectly, but if I go to this by `$location.path('/tab/rate-profiles')` the `$ionicPlatform.ready` never resolves.

Some information:

1 - The app was generated by `ionic start myProject tabs` so all the routes that I make was writed with the same code pattern.
2 - I'm running on Asus Zenfone 5 Android 4.4.2

Another strange thing, If I write `console.log('here!')` in the beginning of `RateProfilesCtrl` and go to this controller using `<a href="#/tab/rate-profiles"...` it executes once, but when I go using `$location.path('/tab/rate-profiles')` it executes twice.

Comment: what is the use case for using `$location.path('/tab/rate-profiles')`

Comment: In my routes I have this `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dispatcher');` so when I open the app my dispatcher controller look at localstorage, if I have data on it I send the app to view `rate-profiles`  with `$location.path('/tab/rate-profiles')`

Comment: that should be `$state.go('tab.rate-profiles')`